# html css background image of div box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div box with an background image for my website.
The div box itself works perfectly but there is no background image in it.
Anyone have an idea?

```css
.box {
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px grey;
margin: 100px auto;
border: 10px solid red;
background-image: url(/img/header.jpg);
background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: Almost certainly a path issue.

Comment: Check the dev tools for errors. Sure the path is correct?

Comment: Try `url(./img/header.jpg);`? Number of dots depends on the path

Answer (score 0):

Try pointing to the absolute path:

```
.box {
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px grey;
margin: 100px auto;
border: 10px solid red;
background-image: url("http://www.website.com/img/header.jpg");
background-size: cover;

}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Loq13pzu/)